# request for member ... in something not a structure or union|

Tags: c

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
 {
    struct square k;
    k=makesquare(7,7);
    insquare(&k,10);
    return 0;
}

//makesquare makes dinamic 2D array

 void insquare(struct square *p, unsigned char value) {
    int i,j;
    for(i = 0; i < p.height; i++)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

I'm very beginner at C and pointers. In line with "p.height" i have error:
request for member 'height' in something not a structure or union

Help please.

Comment: p is a pointer to structure, so you need to use different syntax:

    for(i = 0; i < p->height; i++)

Comment: This is covered in every introductory C textbook.

Comment: @JIghtuse Put it in an answer.

Answer (score 5):

[copied from comment]

p is a pointer to structure, so you need to use different syntax:

```
for(i = 0; i < p->height; i++)
```

Please read some book on C.

Comment: Just to clarify, the "p->x" operator is equivalent to "(*p).x." So it allows you to simultaneously dereference a pointer to a structure and then select an element of that structure.